# SSIS Date in derived column as yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I would need date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format in a ssis derived column,

i am using `(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE()` which is populating as `2013-05-24 00:00:00`

Please suggest...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SSIS Derived Column expression variant:

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE())  + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2)  + 
"-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use unicode:

```
 SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR, 4)(GETDATE()), 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a time part to the date because you're casting to a type of "datetime" care-of the `(DT_DATE)` part of your expression. Pop that out and you should be gold. General formatting guidance:

Convert to YYYY-MM-DD...

```
(DT_WSTR, 30)(DT_DBDATE)@[System::StartTime]
```

Convert to YYYYMMDD...

```
REPLACE( (DT_WSTR, 30)(DT_DBDATE)@[System::StartTime], "-", "")
```