# Date conversion using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to load excel data into a table using SSIS.
In my excel, there is one column 'TRANSACTION DATE'.

```
TRANSACTION_DATE IN EXCEL   TRANSACTION_DATE IN TABLE
01/12/2014  2014-01-12 00:00:00.000
01/12/2014  2014-01-12 00:00:00.000
02/12/2014  2014-02-12 00:00:00.000
05/12/2014  2014-05-12 00:00:00.000
05/12/2014  2014-05-12 00:00:00.000
13/12/2014  2014-12-13 00:00:00.000
16/12/2014  2014-12-16 00:00:00.000
16/12/2014  2014-12-16 00:00:00.000
19/12/2014  2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
20/12/2014  2014-12-20 00:00:00.000
22/12/2014  2014-12-22 00:00:00.000
26/12/2014  2014-12-26 00:00:00.000
29/12/2014  2014-12-29 00:00:00.000
31/12/2014  2014-12-31 00:00:00.000
31/12/2014  2014-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Problem:

If you observe first 5 rows in the table values, the syntax is quite different with other values of the table.it should be (2014-12-01,2014-12-02 etc..). Because of this issue, if I fire a query to sum the values of of another column where DATEPART(MM,TRANSACTION_DATE)=12, The top 5 values are getting excluded.

Table Structure :

```
TRANSACTION_DATE  DATETIME
```

SSIS DATA CONVERSION :

```
TRANSACTION_DATE DT_DBDATE
```

Comment: It would be better to fix the excel data, before it gets close to SQL Server. The `nn/nn/nnnn` format is ambiguous, and apparently, given the opportunity, it's being interpreted as `mm/dd/yyyy`. Only when the first number is higher than 12 is it "obviously" in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I'd recommend switching it to `yyyy-mm-dd` in the excel.

Comment: This answer shows how to change on SSIS (work around) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16732755/1692632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is the first 5 records are being parsed in the American format (MM/DD/YYYY), and the rest of the records are being parsed as DD/MM/YYYY.

Check the datetime format of the cells in Excel to make sure the Locale setting is consistent for all the dates.